How to use nightly toolchain by default in rustrover?
Running tests/bench in files marked with #![feature(test)] gives error in rustrover
`#![feature]` cannot be used on the stable release channel [E0554]

It is because cargo is using the default toolchain (which is not nightly) on my machine.
Is there a setting in Rustrover that can be modified to use nightly toolchain, or maybe a place where one can provide additional flags to cargo?

You have two options:
Switch to the nightly toolchain in the terminal globally:
rustup default nightly

After switching the toolchain, don't forget to reload the project model
Or override it using rust-toolchain file in your project.
